# I'm trying to add php custom snippet in ace editor, but the custom snippets are not available in the editor

Tags: build, ace-editor

I'm trying to add php custom snippet in ace editor. I've added below snippet in "ace-master/lib/ace/snippets/php.snippets" then build the project using "node Makefile.dryice.js".

```
snippet rett
    return true;
snippet retf
    return false;
snippet test_snippet
    echo "This is a test snippet";
```

After building the project, the custom snippet is correctly added in "ace-master/build/src/snippets/php.js" as below

```
snippet rett\n\
    return true;\n\
snippet retf\n\
    return false;\n\
snippet test_snippet\n\
    echo \"This is a test snippet\";";
```

However, the custom snippet is not available in editor. Though other snippets are working just fine.
I've tried clearing browser cache, restarting Apache, reloading editor etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible issue may be that you are using spaces for indentation instead of tabs.
Another issue, may be caused by a bug in ace when it treats the whole line as html if it is html at the end of the line, and doesn't include php snippets on that line.

But generally a better approach is to add snippets in your code instead of rebuilding ace

```
var snippetManager = require("ace/snippets").snippetManager
var text = 'snippet rett\n\
\treturn true;\n\
snippet retf\n\
\treturn false;\n\
snippet test_snippet\n\
\techo \"This is a test snippet\";";'
var snippets = snippetManager.parseSnippetFile(text, "php");
snippetManager.register(snippets, "php");
```

or even directly add snippets as json

```
snippetManager.register([
    {
        "tabTrigger": "rett",
        "name": "rett",
        "content": "return true;"
    },
    {
        "tabTrigger": "retf",
        "name": "retf",
        "content": "return false;"
    },
    {
        "tabTrigger": "test_snippet",
        "name": "test_snippet",
        "content": "echo \"This is a test snippet\";\";"
    }
], "php")
```